# Topological characterization of invertible real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer. Consider the topological space $M_n$ of $n$-by-$n$ matrices with real entries.

Can you give a short non-constructive proof of the existence of a continuous function $M_n\to\mathbb{R}$ sending invertible matrices and only invertible matrices to non-zero real numbers?

Comment: This is not a site for HW questions. Try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is not an HW question.

Comment: @Alexandre: I guess the tricky part is hidden in the "non-constructive" part of the question? Otherwise of course the determinant does the job, but one could argue that $\operatorname{det}$ is constructive - although this is up for debate, I guess. I kind of agree that this is is not a HW question but should still be expanded or given more details about what "non-constructive" means here, specifically.

Answer (score 5):

Linear maps on $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous and so, if one is invertible, also its sufficiently small perturbations are. It follows that invertible matrices form an open set in the space $\operatorname{M}_n$, hence non-invertible matrices form a closed set $C$.

But $\operatorname{M}_n$ is a metrizable space, hence a [perfectly normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) space. It follows, by Urysohn Lemma, that every closed set is a zero set of a continuous function. In other words, there exists a continuous function $f \colon \operatorname{M}_n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=C$, and we are done.

We might also use the fact that, by Tietze Extension Theorem, in perfectly normal spaces two closed sets can be precisely separated by continuous functions. So, we can find a continuous function $f \colon \operatorname{M}_n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f^{-1}(0)=C, \quad f^{-1}(1) = \{\operatorname{id} \}.$$

Note that, in this second proof, we surely have $f \neq \lambda \det$, because the identity is the only preimage of $1$ via $f$.

Comment: Great answer, I had never seen the Tietze extension theorem applied this way.